# Why are my SOAP v2 WS-I calls so slow (7-10 sec. per product update)?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, api, soap, event-observer

We're using the Magento SOAP v2 API with WS-I.

The problem is, that the SOAP calls are extremly slow (7-10 seconds per product!).
We're calling catalogProductUpdate without images.
The shop itself runs fine, just the SOAP call is slow.
We activated the Cache and deaktivated the Index for performance boosting (that helpend on many other shops when the SOAP import was slow).

I put log-messages in various files to find out where it goes wrong. This is the combination log from function calls and dispatch events:

```
20.03.2013 14:17:43: Mage_Api_V2_SoapController
20.03.2013 14:17:43: dispatchEvent: controller_action_postdispatch_api_v2_soap_index
20.03.2013 14:17:43: dispatchEvent: controller_action_postdispatch_api
20.03.2013 14:17:43: dispatchEvent: controller_action_postdispatch
20.03.2013 14:17:43: dispatchEvent: controller_front_send_response_before
20.03.2013 14:17:43: dispatchEvent: http_response_send_before
20.03.2013 14:17:43: dispatchEvent: controller_front_send_response_after
20.03.2013 14:17:43: Mage::run
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: core_collection_abstract_load_before
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: core_collection_abstract_load_after
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: core_collection_abstract_load_before
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: core_collection_abstract_load_after
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: core_collection_abstract_load_before
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: core_collection_abstract_load_after
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: controller_front_init_before
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: controller_front_init_routers
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: model_load_after
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: core_abstract_load_after
20.03.2013 14:17:51: Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front
20.03.2013 14:17:51: Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front
20.03.2013 14:17:51: Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: core_locale_set_locale
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: controller_action_predispatch
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: controller_action_predispatch_api
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: controller_action_predispatch_api_v2_soap_index
20.03.2013 14:17:51: Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action
20.03.2013 14:17:51: Mage_Api_Model_Server
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: Mage_Api_Model_Server_Handler_Abstract
20.03.2013 14:17:51: Neues Update: 2110000438920 
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: model_load_after
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: core_abstract_load_after
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: model_load_before
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: catalog_product_load_before
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: model_load_after
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: catalog_product_load_after
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: prepareDataForSave Dauer: 0.75447800 1363789071-0.77473800 1363789071=0.02026
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: catalog_product_validate_before
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: catalog_product_validate_after
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: application_clean_cache
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: model_save_before
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: catalog_product_save_before
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: model_load_after
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: core_abstract_load_after
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: catalog_product_media_save_before
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: application_clean_cache
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: model_save_after
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: catalog_product_save_after
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: model_save_after
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: core_collection_abstract_load_before
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: core_collection_abstract_load_after
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: model_load_before
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: core_abstract_load_before
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: model_load_after
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: core_abstract_load_after
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: start_process_event_cataloginventory_stock_item_save
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: index_process_change_status
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: index_process_change_status
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: index_process_change_status
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: model_save_before
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: core_abstract_save_before
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: model_save_after
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: core_abstract_save_after
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: end_process_event_cataloginventory_stock_item_save
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: start_index_events_catalog_product_mass_action
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: end_index_events_catalog_product_mass_action
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: core_collection_abstract_load_before
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: core_collection_abstract_load_after
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: start_process_event_catalog_product_save
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: index_process_change_status
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: index_process_change_status
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: index_process_change_status
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: index_process_change_status
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: index_process_change_status
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: index_process_change_status
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: index_process_change_status
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: index_process_change_status
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: index_process_change_status
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: model_save_before
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: core_abstract_save_before
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: model_save_after
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: core_abstract_save_after
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: end_process_event_catalog_product_save
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: model_save_commit_after
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: core_abstract_save_commit_after
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: model_save_commit_after
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: cataloginventory_stock_item_save_commit_after
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: model_save_commit_after
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: core_abstract_save_commit_after
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: model_save_commit_after
20.03.2013 14:17:52: dispatchEvent: catalog_product_save_commit_after
20.03.2013 14:17:52: update Dauer: 0.02026
```

The interesting part is:

```
20.03.2013 14:17:43: Mage::run
20.03.2013 14:17:51: dispatchEvent: resource_get_tablename
...
20.03.2013 14:17:51: Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front
```

There are always 7-10 seconds between `Mage::run` and the next event/function call in `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front`.
Any ideas what can go wrong here?

We have the same problem with another shop (on another server, different customer) with the same settings, where an update takes 15 seconds.

Comment: Have you tried to debug config load times? That seems like most likely reason for a delay

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "debug config load times"?

Comment: I guess Petar is talking about the time it takes to compile the config node tree.

Comment: Yes, I mean time it takes to bootstrap Magento before actual request is processed. Also, why is Mage::run in the log at all? I do not see such call in api.php

Comment: I've got a quick performance tip below, but if you/your developers are interested in getting elbows deep in the API, this API series covers the dispatch in detail and may help track down performance problems: http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#magento_api

Comment: How many products are you updating in a single call?

Comment: 1 product at a time

Comment: @DanielLang Seems like you might be missing a cache hit somewhere, or your server's resource constrained, or you have some custom event handler code that runs inefficiently in an API context.  I'd just trace the execution chain down and add temporary brute force logging as you go until you find the culprit.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your comments! Mage::run is in the log because i logged "Mage::run" directly in the index.php to see at what time it's called. We update 1 product with 1 call.

Comment: @AlanStorm: Thanks a lot for the link, I think we need to go deeper...

Comment: Are you experienced with xdebug? You can start the debugger and have a look on all the functions which are called. https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+profile+with+webgrind If you need help, ping me. I'm not experienced with this, but I sat it up and it works :)

Comment: Thank you, everyone! Finally we found out that it was not only the fault of the Magento Shop but a combination of Shop+Connector.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do you have PHP setup to cache the WSDL files? PHP's `SoapServer` implementation (used by Magento) needs to examine the WSDL file *at least* once during a SOAP call, sometimes more than once.  This can create exponential growth in your request times.  Check the setting at

```
System -> Configuration -> Magento Core Api -> Enable WSDL Cache
```

and make sure its set to yes.  This will instruct PHP to cache the WSDL file, which should improve your performance.

Comment: I'm also working on the same project, so I know that yes, we have already enabled the WSDL cache. It made about 1 second difference but that's stil not at lot considering that the whole update call takes 8-10 seconds...

Comment: Right, Enable WSDL Cache in the Backend is set to "Yes".

Comment: Even though this was not the real solution, I select this answer to close the question.

Comment: This brought me from 30 seconds to do an update to 4 seconds. Win.